# Can't see my file

Tags: files

I created a file in desktop I can not see it there , but when I'm running ls command it shows that the file is on Desktop. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Do you not see the file in your desktop folder or in the desktop workspace (like in windows)?

Comment: i can't see the file in my desktop but not in the desktop workplace

Comment: When i m trying to locate the files it says that is on desktop. When I try to delete the file it tells me that the file does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [plugin](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1444/desktop-icons-enhanced/).

Gnome 3.2 removes the option to display desktop icons.

And I've experienced it as a bug on 3.3 myself.
This plugin should solve your issue.